# Django with Heroku-PostgreSQL database horizontal scaling

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

**The problem background**

- I am working on a Django project, which is using PostgreSQL and is hosted on Heroku(also using `heroku-postgres`). After some time, the amount of data becomes very big and that slows down the application.
- I tried replication in order to read from multiple databases, that helped reducing the queue and connection time, but the big table is still the problem.
- I can split the data based on `group` of `users`, different `group` do not need to interact with each other.
- I have read into **Sharding**. But since we use `heroku-postgres`, it's hard to customize the sharding
- So I have come up with 2 different ideas below

**1. The app cluster with multi-db** (Not allowed to embed image yet)

[Please see the design here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8KFg.jpg)

- We can use the `middlewares` and `database-routers` to achieve this
- But not sure if this is friendly with django

**2. The gateway app with multiple sub-apps** (Not allowed to embed image yet)

[Please see the design here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKj3l.jpg)

- This require less effort than the previous design
- Also possible to set region-based sub-apps in the future

**My question is: which of the two is more django-friendly and better for scalability in the long run?**

Comment: How much data do you have (rows and/or size) and what are the queries that are becoming slow? Have you properly indexed your data and optimised your queries?

Comment: @IainShelvington The table that has problem is already around 15GB in size and is growing exponentially. The slow queries are mainly the listing(with ordering and pagination applied). Can't say that the queries are fully optimized, but from the growing data size we'll have to scale it horizontally some day.

Comment: Optimising your queries is always the first thing you should do, it will improve query times, your app response times and reduce resource usage, it's a win-win wether you scale or not. If you scale a non-optimised solution you are just postponing the inevitable, soon you will have to refactor this new design when your queries start performing badly again but it will be a lot more difficult. 15GB is not a lot of data